# Consider whitespace on search while indexing with edge-ngrams

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

I have an index with the following settings:

```
 "analysis" : {
      "analyzer" : {
        "global_search_analyzer" : {
          "filter" : [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer" : "whitespace"
        },
        "global_search_indexer" : {
          "filter" : [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer" : "global_search_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer" : {
        "global_search_tokenizer" : {
          "token_chars" : [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "custom"
          ],
          "custom_token_chars" : "-/[]().,%!\"$#&+'",
          "min_gram" : "2",
          "type" : "edge_ngram",
          "max_gram" : "20"
        }
      }
    }
```

So to explain what I'm doing today - I have the tokenizer, that allows some special chars, and breaks the phrases by white-spaces.

I do, however, want to allow search for longer terms, including two words or more. So for example, if I have this document

```
 {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "ksdfji319bmm",
    "_score" : 11.850912,
    "_source" : {
      "id" : "ksdfji319bmm",
      "keywords" : [
        "MY TEST"            
      ],
      "lastUpdateAt" : "2022-07-11",
      "deleted" : false
    }
  }
```

This is the mapping of the index for "keywords" field:

```
    "keywords" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "analyzer" : "global_search_indexer",
      "search_analyzer" : "global_search_analyzer"
    },
```

I want to be able to search, and find, this document by either searching "TEST" or "MY TEST". Today only searching "TEST" would work for that matter.

I tried removing the "whitespace" tokenizer and changing it to the "keyword" tokenizer but I keep getting the same result.

Comment: Can you also share your mapping and search query?

Comment: are you still facing issue? if yes, would you mind providing the details I asked earlier

Comment: @Amit - Sorry, I somehow missed your comment. Thanks for trying to help! I added the mapping. Let me know if there's any other details I should share

Comment: thanks could you also share the search query, i guess you are just using simple  `term` query hence not getting the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your search query, since you have not provided one, I have created the local index with your mapping and settings and indexed the sample document that you provided and used simple `match` query that worked in both cases `TEST` or `MY TEST` and brings document that contains `MY TEST` in `keywords` field.

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "keywords": "MY TEST"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search result**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "72938740",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.5753642,
                "_source": {
                    "keywords": "MY TEST"
                }
            }
        ]
```

And search query with just `TEST`

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "keywords": "TEST"
        }
    }
}
```

And SR

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "72938740",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.2876821,
                "_source": {
                    "keywords": "MY TEST"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry for not publishing the search words and for replying slowly (I'm part time there). I'm not sure that's the issue as the query I used was I think the same. Tomorrow I'm there and will be able  to check your answer again.

Comment: @Avi, no worries, will look into it more once i get more update from u

Comment: Thanks Amit, I realized what was the problem with this solution. In this case it searches for both "MY" and "TEST" as two different searchs. If you add another document with just "TEST" (not "MY TEST") by searching "MY TEST" you'll find both docs, although you only want the one that has the phrase "MY TEST"

Comment: @Avi glad to hear back from you, and hear that you were able to find the solution, if my answer was helpful please upvote it and you can write your own answer so that its more valuable

Comment: Hey Amit, as I said, this doesn't solve the issue :(